# SendKeys to Excel Input Box (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to do is run a VBA file that opens an excel workbook, starts a macro with an input box, enters text into that input box, presses enter, and then the macro continues to run.

What I have so far is this with "GetData" being the name of the macro:

```
strPath = "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\ExcelFile.xlsm" 
strMacro = "GetData"

Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objApp.Visible = True

Set wbToRun = objApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath) 
objApp.Run strMacro

objApp.SendKeys "Sample"
objApp.SendKeys "~"
```

The problem I'm having is that SendKeys doesn't activate until after the macro is done running. After the Input Box appears, it just stays there until I close it. This results in the macro doing nothing then the word "Sample" being entered into a cell then "Enter" being pressed.

My question is this: how do I get SendKeys to enter values into the Input Box?

Comment: can you Change the macro 'strmacro' into a function like strfunction(inputboxtext as string), and then when calling the function send the text you want in the Inputbox? of Course there is no Need for an Inputbox anymore then.

Answer (score 0):

You dont use `SendKeys` on an `InputBox`, you just specify a default value:

```
x = InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "Default Value")
```

If that does not meet your needs, then it gets a bit more complicated. Have your calling program write the value to a file before it calls the macro, and then have the macro read that file into a variable that the `InputBox` then uses as its default value.

But if it's also "pressing enter" then what is the point in using an `InputBox` in the first place? It seems pointless.